# save a image from base64

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below code to save image in asp.net with C#. There is no error while saving but I am unable to specify the path in the function.

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        image.Save("test", ImageFormat.Png);
        //image.Save("test.png");
        return image;
  }
```

If I put the physical path using `server.mappath` it producing an error GDI exception. What I am doing wrong.

Comment: Access rights to location perhaps?

Comment: Please Paste Exact Exception ????